# Where can I enabled the switch in the In App Purchase Capability in Xcode 12?

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, capability

I noticed Xcode 12 has changed a lot new redesign interface so capability has no longer shows up the switch to enable or disable in Xcode 12. So can someone find the enable inside the IAP Capability to show up the checkmark to make sure enabled or not? I can't get shows up the IAP in my devices due to the needs that enable the IAP to checkmark in the Capability.

Let me know. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If already enabled, you should see it under the Signing & Capabilities Tab.

[image]

if you can't see it, then to enable IAP with your target selected,

[image]

Then search for in-app and select it.

[image]

Comment: yeah i did, but problems IAP won't show up on my devices and i checked all code was prefect works so i have no idea why. I checked it need show like this https://ibb.co/0f3wW6B

Comment: @AntonioAdrianChavez that is not Xcode 12 in the screen shot, that an older version of Xcode.

Comment: Yes, I know. So Xcode 12 gives me that is all done after I enabled the IAP capabilities?

Comment: yap that's all you need to do to enable it.